# Setting up Firebase Firestore for offline mode in an Android app using Dagger Hilt

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing an Android application intended for areas where internet connectivity can be unstable or non-existent. Therefore, I would like to implement offline mode using Firebase Firestore. Currently, I am using `Dagger Hilt` for dependency injection in my project.

While researching, I noticed that many implementations using the Realtime Database set up offline mode in the Application class. However, when trying to achieve this using `Dagger Hilt` in my Firebase module, I encountered the following error:

---

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class FirebaseModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideFirebaseAuth(): FirebaseAuth = Firebase.auth

    @Provides
    fun provideFirestore(): FirebaseFirestore {
        val settings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
            .setLocalCacheSettings(
                PersistentCacheSettings.Builder() // Error: Cannot access '<init>': it is private in 'Builder'
                    .build()
            )
            .build()
        return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(settings)
    }
}
```

---

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class AppHiltApp : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // Set up offline persistence here?
        
    }
}
```

---

The specific error I'm facing is "Cannot access '': it is private in 'Builder'". I would like to know the best approach to set up offline mode in Firestore using Dagger Hilt, considering the need to save data in the cache for later synchronization with the server when the connection is available.

I appreciate your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the constructor of the [PersistentCacheSettings.Builder](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/PersistentCacheSettings.Builder) class is private. As you can see it is not present in the official documentation, hence the error. Please also note that the [FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder#setLocalCacheSettings()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder#setLocalCacheSettings(com.google.firebase.firestore.LocalCacheSettings)) method takes an argument of type [LocalCacheSettings](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/LocalCacheSettings). So such an object should be passed to the `setLocalCacheSettings()` method. So there are two available options for you, [PersistentCacheSettings](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/PersistentCacheSettings) and [MemoryCacheSettings](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/MemoryCacheSettings), each with different configuration options. It's up to you to decide which one fits best to your use case.

According to the official documentation regarding [configuring offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence), here is how you can you can use it in code:

```
val settings = firestoreSettings {
    // Use memory cache
    setLocalCacheSettings(memoryCacheSettings {
        //Add what you need
    })
    // Use persistent disk cache (default)
    setLocalCacheSettings(persistentCacheSettings {
        //Add what you need
    })
}
db.firestoreSettings = settings
```

So you have to provide what implementation you consider is the best.

If it's only about persistence, any database operation initializes Firestore with the default settings, `setPersistanceEnabled(true)` and `setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(false)`. So you don't have much to do.